# Should PM2 God Daemon always be running?

Tags: pm2

I use pm2 to deal with node projects. Even when all projects are stopped via pm2, I see that pm2 God Daemon is always running and consuming about ~27M Ram. Here how it looks on ps aux: 
`nodeuser  2577  ?   Ssl  18:02   0:01 PM2 v0.15.10: God Daemon`

The question is, is it built to be that way? Should pm2 God Daemon always be running? However if it is the case, I would like to know why because it didn't make sense to me.

Can I kill pm2 God Daemon via pm2? Or simply kill with `kill -9 pid`?

Answer (score 14):

With pm2 you can kill the god daemon with

```
pm2 kill
```

Comment: Thats bad, as it nukes you config as well. Not ideal if you want to restart the god daemon under systemd rather that stand alone but in its existing state

Comment: @krad pm2 will utilize saved config and will resurrect daemonized processes if `pm2 save` and `pm2 startup` have been used. How will `pm2 kill` impact systemd in such case?

Comment: Depending on how the service is setup it will either restart or fault